# Atribuir variáveis com números diferentes, com caracteres curinga no DOS

Tags: cmd

Olá, como faço para atribuir essas variáveis mesmo com os números diferentes? Tentei caracteres curinga tipo "*", mas sem sucesso... Obrigado desde já.

```
set lstate=Pending
set cstate=%_Yellow%
set arrow= 
call :dk_color2 %_White% "%arrow1% Windows Activation" %cstate1% "       %lstate1%"
call :dk_color2 %_White% "%arrow2% Windows Update" %cstate2% "       %lstate2%"
call :dk_color2 %_White% "%arrow3% Windows Optimization" %cstate3% "         %lstate3%"
call :dk_color2 %_White% "%arrow4% Windows Customization" %cstate4% "        %lstate4%"
call :dk_color2 %_White% "%arrow5% Default Programs" %cstate5% "         %lstate5%"
call :dk_color2 %_White% "%arrow6% Check drivers" %cstate6% "            %lstate6%"
call :dk_color2 %_White% "%arrow7% Scan Errors" %cstate7% "              %lstate7%"
call :dk_color2 %_White% "%arrow8% Clean" %cstate8% "                %lstate8%"
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor eu não entendi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a ideia é definir uma variável dinamicamente, você simplesmente pode fazer isso:

```
set CHAVE=1
set foo%CHAVE%=1000

set CHAVE=BAR
set foo%CHAVE%=exemplo

echo foo1: %foo1%
echo fooBAR: %fooBAR%
```

No exemplo `%CHAVE%` é uma variável, ao usar `set foo%CHAVE%` você poderá alterar a variável dinamicamente, assim duas variáveis foram alteradas pelo `foo%CHAVE%`, foram `foo1` e `fooBAR`.

Se você tem um conjunto de variáveis e você precisa atribuir o mesmo valor para todas você pode usar um `for`, exemplo se você deseja atribuir as variáveis `arrow1`, `arrow2`, `arrow3`, `arrow4`, etc, exemplo:

```
@echo off

for %%F in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) do (
    set arrow%%F=%%F
)

echo %arrow1%
echo %arrow2%
echo %arrow3%
echo %arrow4%
echo %arrow9%
```

O `%%F` é a variável que será um dos valores de 1 a 9, você pode alterar o `=%%F` para o valor que deseja atribuir a um grupo de variáveis.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu precisava, muito obrigado...